# Sum() using IIF() or Where Clause in MS Access

Tags: sum, ms-access-2007, where-clause, iif, ms-access-reports

In my Report:
BID is Billing Customer ID a TEXT FIELD.
NPROFIT is Net Profit a NUMERIC FIELD.

My Query sums NPROFIT for all BID.
Using the statement:
=Sum([NPROFIT])

I need to sum the NProfit column ONLY for certain BID values ... ACTUALLY, I WANT TO SUM() 4 OF 10 BID and exclude the other 6 of 10

I have tried:
IIF([BID]=403490, =Sum([NPROFIT]), "None")

That does not work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sum(IIf([BID]=403490, [NPROFIT], 0))
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav and I agree, that looks right to me ... but ... here is the error I get in return: Extra ) in query expression 'First([Sum(IIf([BID]=403490, [NPROFIT],0))])'

Comment: As additional info, I always get a result of 0 ... When I add the '=' in front of the Sum ... like this....                                   =Sum(IIf([BID]=403490, [NPROFIT], 0))

Comment: wait ... I am ahead of myself... The CORRECT answer was 0 in my example and then I changed the BID and again got the CORRECT result.... now do you know how do I can add additional BID's so I can SUM those selected BID's only and exclude any not selected in the TOTAL... Can I nest the IIf() statements to accomplish that?

Comment: No `First` should be needed. To sum per BID, `Group By` BID.

Comment: I went ahead and tried the idea of nested IIf() statements and it worked like a charm with the help of your code suggestion...THANKS a bunch! That saved me a lot of GREIF and a LOT of time too!                                     here is the final code and there may be a more elegant way to do this but, this works beautifully so ... thanks again! =Sum(IIf([BID]=403490,[NPROFIT],0)+IIf([BID]=375130,[NPROFIT],0)+IIf([BID]=214900,[NPROFIT],0)+IIf([BID]=368380,[NPROFIT],0))